# How can I animate a button's color so it changes from right to left?

Tags: qt, qml

I have this simple `Rectangle` and i want to animate it's color change in a way that the new color fills in from right to the left of it.

```
Rectangle{
    width:100
    height:150
    color:"green"
}
```

What should I do? What kind of `Animation` or `Transition` do I need in this case?

Comment: Two possible solution are: (1) animating a gradient and (2) using a second moving rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw a simple Rectangle with the original color, "green" in this example:

```
Rectangle{
    width:100
    height:150
    color:"green"
}
```

Then draw another rectangle on top but with width equal to 0 and the new color, "red" in this example:

```
Rectangle{
    id: newColorRect
    width:0
    height:150
    color:"red"
}
```

Finally with a animation you can animate the color change, changing the width of the newColorRect rectangle.

```
PropertyAnimation {
    id: colorAnimation
    target: newColorRect
    properties: "width"
    to: 100
    duration: 1000
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    colorAnimation.start()
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But animates from left to right, how do i change it from right to left?

Comment: Easy, start with width equal to 100 and then change the value to 0 using the animation.